# Phpinfo() from xampp doesn't show php-redis extension (UBUNTU 20.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, redis, xampp, phpredis

I installed Redis-server and PHP-Redis, as well as PHP-igbinary on my hardware but it seems that my xampp php_info() does not show me the extensions as if it did not take into account my installations.

This is a real concern because I cannot launch my company's projects because they are blocked by this message: `"Attempted to load class \" Redis \ "from the global namespace. \ NDid you forget a \" use \ "statement?"`

FYI I used pecl to install PHP-Redis and igbinary, apt-get for Redis-server.

So I'm trying to install PHP-Redis on the xampp server but I can't find any solution to my problem on the internet (and I spent a lot of days there). I am not an expert in system admin so someone has a solution to my problem I thank him.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install php-redis
apache2ctl restart
```